# Paypal Masspay API Masspay input parse error

Tags: php, paypal, masspay

I am using Paypal MassPay API in php.

My code was working fine but now I am getting this error.

```
MassPay failed: 
Array ( [TIMESTAMP] => 2014/07/06T17%3a27%3a04Z 
[CORRELATIONID] => 5d6bf81231859 
[ACK] => Failure 
[VERSION] => 51%2e0 
[BUILD] => 11753088 
[L_ERRORCODE0] => 10314 
[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Masspay input parse error 
[L_LONGMESSAGE0] =>The input to the masspay server is incorrect e Please make sure that you are using a correctly formatted input e 
[L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
```

Anyone has idea why I am getting this error now? I can provide code if required.

This is the main class:

```
Paypal_class.php

<?php

  class Paypal {

        public function __construct($username, $password, $signature) {
            $this->username = urlencode($username);
            $this->password = urlencode($password);
            $this->signature = urlencode($signature);
            $this->version = urlencode("51.0");
            $this->api = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";

            //The functions can be modified but need to be urlencoded
            $this->type = urlencode("EmailAddress");
            $this->currency = urlencode("USD");
            $this->subject = urlencode("Instant Paypal Payment");
        }

        public function pay($email, $amount, $note="Instant Payment") {
            $string = "&EMAILSUBJECT=".$this->subject."&RECEIVERTYPE=".$this->type."&CURRENCYCODE=".$this->currency;
            $string .= "&L_EMAIL0=".urlencode($email)."&L_Amt0=".urlencode($amount)."&L_NOTE0=".urlencode($note);

            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->api);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            $request = "METHOD=MassPay&VERSION=".$this->version."&PWD=".$this->password."&USER=".$this->username."&SIGNATURE=".$this->signature."$string";

            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
            $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);
            if(!$httpResponse) {
                exit("MassPay failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
            }

            $httpResponseArray = explode("&", $httpResponse);
            $httpParsedResponse = array();
            foreach ($httpResponseArray as $i => $value) {
                $tempArray = explode("=", $value);
                if(sizeof($tempArray) > 1) {
                    $httpParsedResponse[$tempArray[0]] = $tempArray[1];
                }
            }

            if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponse)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponse)) {
                exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($request) to ".$this->api);
            }

            return $httpParsedResponse;
        }

    }
?>
```

Calling this class with example.php file:

```
<?php

    require "paypal_class.php";
    $paypal = new Paypal("example.com", "xyz, "abc");

    $send_payment = $paypal->pay("abc@gmail.com", ".001", "Thanks for an amazing service");

    if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($send_payment["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($send_payment["ACK"])) {
        exit('MassPay Completed Successfully: '.print_r($send_payment, true));
    } else {
        exit('MassPay failed: ' . print_r($send_payment, true));
    }
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: Seems to be telling you that your request is incorrect.  Need to see a sample of the request to help.

Comment: Thanks! I am adding code to this question.

Comment: I wasn't asking for a sample of the code, but rather a sample of the raw API request that gets generated from that code.  Basically, the final value that you're getting for $request and actually passing into CURL.  PayPal apparently isn't liking what it's receiving, so we need to look at that and see what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem. I changed the amount to be sent from "0.001" to "0.01", this code worked. 
May be Paypal MassPay API doesn't deal with amount having more than two digits after decimal.